Multiple data type column in Power Query
I have a column with multiple data type in Power BI as the following below. How I can convert/modify to Currency ( Fixed decimal number)
old_price
null
990
SR 4,040
SR 50/4 pack
SR 445/2 pack
null
895
SR 50/4 pack
......
I tried some of ways below

replace value
Added Custom column with formular: Convert, Number.From text
However, it did not work and get error message

I would like to convert this mixed data into Fixed decimal number

Having a mixed type column is generally a very bad idea.  You could use something like that:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    TransformColumn = Table.TransformColumns(
        Source,
        {
            {"Column1", each if Value.Is(_, type number) then Number.ToText(_, "C") else _}
        }
)
in
    TransformColumn

Number.ToText(_, "C") - is used to format string as currency.
